# Need regular expression to match first occurence based on first value need to get second value

Tags: python

input :

```
(prototype/rajesh_5678)(name=rajesh)
(prototype/magesh_5679)(name=magesh)
(prototype/kiran_5680)(name=kiran)
```

needed output using regex:

```
[prototype/rajesh_5678,rajesh]
[prototype/magesh_5679, magesh]
[prototype/kiran_5680,kiran]
```

is it possible to get the data like that using regular expression in python?

Comment: What are the inputs and what are the expected outputs?

Comment: why not use `.replace(")(name=", ", ").replace("(", "[").replace(")", "]")` without regex

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pair of capture groups to regex for each of those elements

```
import re
>>> s = '(prototype/rajesh_5678)(name=rajesh)(prototype/magesh_5679)(name=magesh)(prototype/kiran_5680)(name=kiran)'
>>> re.findall(r'\(([\w\d/_]+)\)\(name=(\w+)\)', s)
[('prototype/rajesh_5678', 'rajesh'), ('prototype/magesh_5679', 'magesh'), ('prototype/kiran_5680', 'kiran')]
```

[RegExr demo with details](https://regexr.com/6l0s1)